# How to get width and height with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code:

```
function uploadFile(){
            var file2 = document.getElementById('file1').files;
            for(var i = 0; i < file2.length; i++) {
                var file = file2[i];
                var formdata = new FormData(); // This is image
                formdata.append("file1", file[i]);
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
        }
```

how to get image width and height from `new FormData`?
i need this for crop image

Answer (score 2):

Answered here: [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

```
var width = file.clientWidth;
var height = file.clientHeight;
```